# Terraform: referencing resources created using a map of objects variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am a bit new to Terraform and learning.  I have the following defined in my varaibles.tf as a map of objects, which will allow me to configure multiple subnets (currently only 1):

```
variable "subnets" {
  type        = map(object({name=string, cidr=string, az=string, public=bool}))
  default     = {
    "public_subnet" = {
       name="public",
       cidr="10.123.1.0/24",
       az="us-east-1a",
       public=true
   }
}
```

In main.tf i have the following:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "subnets" {
  for_each                = var.subnets
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  cidr_block              = each.value.cidr
  availability_zone       = each.value.az
  map_public_ip_on_launch = each.value.public 
  
  tags = {
    Name = "${each.value.name}_subnet"
  }
}
```

Now my questions are how would i code the aws_route_table_association and aws_instance to make use of a specific subnet from my varaible map?
Normally if i didnt have  a map i would do something like this:

```
resource "aws_route_table_association" "public_rta" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.subnet.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public_rt.id
}
```

Im not sure how to references a subnet's id created in a loop in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work you would have to use `for_each` with the route table association resource as well (or reference different keys). In the scenario you want all your subnets attached to the same route table, you can use [resource chaining with `for_each`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#chaining-for_each-between-resources) in this case:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "subnets" {
  for_each                = var.subnets
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  cidr_block              = each.value.cidr
  availability_zone       = each.value.az
  map_public_ip_on_launch = each.value.public 
  tags = {
    Name = "${each.value.name}_subnet"
  }

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public_rta" {
  for_each       = aws_subnet.subnets
  subnet_id      = each.value.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public_rt.id
}
```

Comment: oh i see.  So for every subnet created, there should be a route table association made.
When it comes to the "aws_instance" provider though, i should be able to specify only one subnet, no? if i use a for_each, would it not create multiple instances?  I would ideally like to also configure by instance, such that i can choose whether its on a particular subnet defined in my config/vars file

Comment: Yes, with `for_each` multiple instances would be created. For an instance you need only one and you could reference a subnet by the key used to create it, e.g., `aws_subnet.subnets["public_subnet"].id`.

Comment: Oh..i didnt know that key used in the config is can be used like that.  great, thanks!